# how to disable WordPress flash up-loader?

Tags: uploads

how to disable WordPress flash up-loader and force to use browser up-loader instead ?
any solution, is there any function code i can use?

Comment: flash uploader is no more used on the current version of WordPress

Answer (score 1):

```
function disable_flash_uploader() {
    return false;
}

add_filter( 'flash_uploader', 'disable_flash_uploader', 1 );
```

Or disable/uninstall the plug in

Comment: unfortunately it does't work with latest edition of WordPress

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the Browser uploaders, there is less trouble and therefore easy to abandon the added value of Flash uploaders, like loading multiple files simultaneously. You can disable the Flash uploader by using a filter. This can be done either in your theme, stored in the `functions.php` or in a Plugin.

```
function disable_flash_uploader() {
    return false;
}

add_filter( 'flash_uploader', 'disable_flash_uploader', 1 );
```

Comment: create_function was deprecated

Comment: unfortunately it does't work with latest edition of WordPress